# Maximum number of childs in a chain of processes in C

Tags: c, subprocess, fork

Which is the maximum number of processes that can be created in a process chain using c?

I am using Ubuntu 18.04. And gnu-90 compiler. Is there a variable which contains how many processes can be created in a process chain? 
How can I handle errors in case I can no longer create new processes in the chain?

Comment: You can spot the error by observing the return value from `fork()`. The limit is controlled by the o/s.  It’s likely to be substantial.  You might find a limit in `<limits.h>`.  Offhand, I'd expect it to be something like `PROC_MAX`.

Comment: I wonder what it is that is coded in C `-std=gnu-90`?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I doubt you could find that in `limits.h` or any other library header since it's a runtime configurable value that depends on multiple different factors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which is the maximum number of processes that can be created in a process chain using c?

There is a limit on the number of processes a user can create:

```
[max@supernova:~] $ cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=18.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=bionic
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS"

[max@supernova:~] $ ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 128103
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 8589934592
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 65536
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8515
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 128103 <---------------- here
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Note that *max user processes* is just a limit rather than a requirement, your system may run out of memory before you are able to create that many processes.